# Social icons move on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a layout for my website and I have a problem with overwriting CSS that controls social icons. It's looks like that: http://hotarubi.pl/docuworks/index.html

I want the icons move up on hover, but the parent selector has attributes that block the standard method of doing this.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Docuworks</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="head">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="images/theme/fb.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="images/theme/tweeter.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="social" src="images/theme/rss.png" /></a>
</header>

<nav id="menu">
    <div class="bg-repeat"></div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
body 
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/theme/bg.png);
}

img.social
{   top: 50px;
    left: 80%;
    z-index:-1;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -50px;   
}

img.social :hover 
{
    top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

#menu
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(images/theme/logo.png), url(images/theme/login.png);
    background-position: top left, top right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

div.bg-repeat
{
    margin: 0 314px 0 258px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(images/theme/bg-r.png) repeat-x;    
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone would help me solve this issue :)

**@edit**

Okay, I managed do solve it. The code should look like this:

```
img.social
{   top: 50px;
    left: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -50px;   
}

img.social:hover 
{
    top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -25px !important;
}
```

But know another problem appeared. The menu bar below is moving on hover too xD So I got to figure out how to stop it from moving. Any ideas how to do it?

**@edit 2**

Got it right this time and here's the code:

```
body 
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/theme/bg.png);
}

img.social
{   
    top: 50px;
    left: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

img.social:hover 
{
    top: 25px;  
}

#menu
{   
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(images/theme/logo.png), url(images/theme/login.png);
    background-position: top left, top right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

div.bg-repeat
{
    margin: 0 314px 0 258px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(images/theme/bg-r.png) repeat-x;    
}
```

For future reference if someone happen to come across them same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong selector here:

```
img.social :hover { ... }
```

That would select descendants of image elements with class "social" in their hover state - but an image does not have any descendant elements.

You want

```
img.social:hover { ... }
```

instead - that defines the `:hover` formatting that for the image itself.

Comment: Well, that' because you have other elements laying on top of the images (try right click and "inspect element with firebug" or whatever dev tools you are using - and you will end up selecting body or header) - so your images are never actually hovered.

Comment: I've deleted the header section and it's strange that the browser doesn't even see the links.

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks for the tips. They helped me solve this on my own :)